# Comparing two columns in a pandas DataFrame and filling in missing values for one of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Frame with 2 columns with missing values:

```
   name   code
0   A      12
1   B      39
2   C      23
3   A      12
4   NaN    12
5   NaN    39
6   C      23
7   NaN    39
```

I need to fill the missing value as follows:

```
   name   code
0   A      12
1   B      39
2   C      23
3   A      12
4   A      12
5   B      39
6   C      23
7   B      39
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a reverse mapping of codes to non-null names, then use that to map missing values back:

```
mapping = dict(df.dropna()[['code', 'name']].values)
# mapping = df.set_index('code')['name'].dropna().to_dict()

df['name'] = df['name'].fillna(df['code'].map(mapping))
df

  name  code
0    A    12
1    B    39
2    C    23
3    A    12
4    A    12
5    B    39
6    C    23
7    B    39
```

You can perform an in-place update as well.

```
df['name'].update(df['code'].map(mapping))
df

  name  code
0    A    12
1    B    39
2    C    23
3    A    12
4    A    12
5    B    39
6    C    23
7    B    39
```